# installation visual studio 2008 side by side with visual studio 2010 (has been installed)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, installation, side-by-side

i installed vs 2010 (with telerik components) with ms sql server 2008 r2 on my system...

alo ms office 2010 is there...

i have many projects in vs 2008 that in do not want to convert 4 vs2010...

is it possible to install vs 2008 side by side 2010?

mean could this installation make damages on sql server and vs 2010 files?

also my visual studio 2008 is vista support...

should i get a new ver compatible with windows 7.

(my os is 7)

thanks in future advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would always recommend that, if you're wanting to install an earlier version of a tool, that you remove the later version, install the earlier version, then re-install the later version.

This is sometimes necessary because the earlier version wants to install some components it depends on, but the later version has installed later versions of these components. In that case, the earlier components will refuse to install, so the whole installer fails.

I've got all 4 Visual Studios between 2003 and 2010 installed on my XP machine, happily working together.

Answer (score 0):

I have VS 2008 installed as well as VS 2010 and I've not seen any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have VSTS 2005, 2008 and VS 2010 Ultimate installed, it is no problem.

I have installed them from oldest to newest version.
Same with SqlServer 2005 and 2008.